# NoSuchMethodError from http-builder for binary content

Tags: groovy

I'm using the http-builder 0.7.1 to fetch binary content. This works fine on Groovy 2/Spock 1, but results in a `NoSuchMethodError` on Groovy 3/Spock 2:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.leftShift(Ljava/io/OutputStream;Ljava/io/InputStream;)Ljava/io/OutputStream;
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.defaultSuccessHandler(HTTPBuilder.java:620)
    at groovyx.net.http.RESTClient.defaultSuccessHandler(RESTClient.java:246)
...
```

The rest client is initialized in a very basic way:

```
restClient = new RESTClient(baseUrl)
restClient.handler.failure = restClient.handler.success
```

Getting the binary content is also done in a trivial way:

```
def response = restClient.get(path: theUrl)
```

The returned content carries these headers:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="MyPhoto.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
```

This code works fine with Groovy 2.5.14 and Spock 1.3-groovy-2.5, but it fails with Groovy 3.0.8 and Spock 2.0-groovy-3.0.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mention, I believe this is a consequence of the upgrade to Groovy 3. A quick look shows that DefaultGroovyMethods `leftShift(OutputStream self, InputStream in)` was previously marked as deprecated and it appears as though it was removed during 3.0's changes (though I can't find exactly where). However, you can still find the same method in IOGroovyMethods.

Your issue is that the RESTClient/HttpBuilder library has not been updated to reflect Groovy's changes. However, you can easily extend the RESTClient and provide an override for the `defaultSuccessHandler` method, pointing the handler to the correct location:

```
@Override
HttpResponseDecorator defaultSuccessHandler(HttpResponseDecorator resp, Object parsedData)
        throws ResponseParseException
{
    try
    {
        //If response is streaming, buffer it in a byte array:
        if (parsedData instanceof InputStream)
        {
            ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            // we've updated the below line
            IOGroovyMethods.leftShift(buffer, (InputStream) parsedData);
            resp.setData(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.toByteArray()))
            return resp;
        }
        if (parsedData instanceof Reader)
        {
            StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter();
            // we've updated the below line
            IOGroovyMethods.leftShift(buffer, (Reader) parsedData);
            resp.setData(new StringReader(buffer.toString()))
            return resp;
        }
        return super.defaultSuccessHandler(resp, parsedData)
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        throw new ResponseParseException(resp, ex);
    }
}
```

Note that Groovy 3 also changed the location of certain XML utils, which may become a problem for the RESTClient in the future. If you ever need to, you can override the existing XML entry in the ParserRegistry in your custom RESTClient.

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot. The code wasn't entirely right but pointed in the right direction. I've updated the code with what works for me.

Comment: A pull request has been opened to address this issue: https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/pull/90

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has the same problem. Here is my implementation based on aspok's answer.

```
package groovyx.net.http;

import groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseDecorator;
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient;
import groovyx.net.http.ResponseParseException;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.IOGroovyMethods;

public class RESTClientNew extends RESTClient {
    public RESTClientNew() { super(); }

    public RESTClientNew( Object defaultURI ) throws URISyntaxException {
        super( defaultURI );
    }

    @Override
    protected HttpResponseDecorator defaultSuccessHandler( HttpResponseDecorator resp, Object data )
            throws ResponseParseException {
        try
        {
            //If response is streaming, buffer it in a byte array:
            if (data instanceof InputStream)
            {
                ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                // we've updated the below line
                IOGroovyMethods.leftShift(buffer, (InputStream) data);
                resp.setData(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.toByteArray()));
                return resp;
            }
            if (data instanceof Reader)
            {
                StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter();
                // we've updated the below line
                IOGroovyMethods.leftShift(buffer, (Reader) data);
                resp.setData(new StringReader(buffer.toString()));
                return resp;
            }
            return super.defaultSuccessHandler(resp, data);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            throw new ResponseParseException(resp, ex);
        }
    }
}
```